# Library of questionnaires

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are working on FHIR questionnaires and I wonder if there is already a library with definitions of FHIR questionnaires. I found GCS example https://www.hl7.org/fhir/questionnaire-example-gcs.html. Is there any place where I can find wider set of such definitions? If not, is it planned to be somehow created / maintained? I can see having such set published as something valuable for the community.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the registry that FHIR.org is standing up in the next few months could be extended to this purpose, but I'm not aware of that being in the near-term plans.  And it's not something that exists yet.  You could submit a change proposal (link at the bottom of each page in the spec) to ensure this idea gets formal consideration